# How to solve this Android SQLite Room DAO error message?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, dao

I don't know what's wrong with below problem?

Code:

CategoryDAO.kt

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDAO {
    @Query("select * from CategoryDesign")
    suspend fun getCategory(): MutableLiveData<List<CategoryDesign>>


}
```

CategoryDesign.kt

```
@Entity
data class CategoryDesign (
    @PrimaryKey
    var categoryDesignID:String,
    var designImage:String,
    var designTitle:String){
    constructor() : this("","","")

    override fun toString(): String {
        return designTitle
    }
}
```

Press Run App button will show error like below:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.util.List<com.squall.searchdesigner.model.CategoryDesign>>).
    public abstract java.lang.Object getCategory(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()


w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC), android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding (DYNAMIC).
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.3"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `CategoryDesign` entity?

Comment: are you using paging lib?

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman I have added CategoryDesign entity.

Comment: @Raghunandan I use ViewPager and RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
I used below code and rebuild project and invalidate caches seems solve this problem.

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDAO {
    @Query("select * from CategoryDesign")
    fun getCategory(): LiveData<MutableList<CategoryDesign>>


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you can use only [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-types) return type. Maybe Room not allows you to use MutableLiveData?